# Laravel - How to install Flowbite along Tailwindcss

Tags: node.js, npm, flowbite

I want to install Flowbite in my existing Laravel/Tailwind installation and I have followed all the steps from here but when they tell me to add the .JS file I just can't seem to find it. I tried to run the default commands `npm run dev` / `npm run prod` but that file just doesn't show up and I can't seem to find any kind of information about it since every blog/article seems to just copy-paste the original 'tutorial' from Flowbite.

1. I added `"./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"`in **content** in tailwind.config.js
2. I added `require('flowbite/plugin')` in **plugins** in tailwind.config.js
3. I run `npm run prod` / `npm run dev`
4. Where is that file?!

I don't think I'm suppose to copy those files from the `node_modules` folder, so what am I missing here?

EDIT:

Importing "import 'flowbite';" in Webpack.mix.js gives me the following error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: Did you checked this : https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/laravel/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I followed. My question is, where do I find flowbite.js? how do I access it? Do I need to import it somehow into tailwind.config.js or something like that?

<script src="../path/to/flowbite/dist/flowbite.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for someone who's having trouble installing flowbite and wants to implementing a none CDN approach and want to utilize the `npm` approach you have to add below script on your `webpack.min.js`

```
   mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .js("./node_modules/flowbite/src/flowbite.js", "public/js")
    .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css", [require("tailwindcss")])
    .postCss("./node_modules/flowbite/src/flowbite.css", "public/css");
```

This will create a flowbite.js inside your public/js together with app.js
then just include it on your layout template before  tag ends the defer is optional and on the head tag the css.

```
 <link href="{{ asset('css/flowbite.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

 <script defer src="{{ asset('js/flowbite.js') }}"></script>
```

Don't forget to restart your server.

Answer (score 3):

This is coming four months late, but this is what worked for me:

I followed the Quickstart from the Flowbite official documentation until the point where the instruction says to: "Include the main JavaScript file to make interactive elements work."

```
<script src="../path/to/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js"></script>
```

Since I couldn't find the said file, I created a new directory in my 'public' folder like so:

```
public/backend/flowbite/dist
```

After which I copied the `flowbite.js` from the flowbite directory in `node_modules` directory into the newly created `dist` directory.

I included the script tag at the bottom of my layout file like so:

```
<script src="{{ asset('backend/flowbite/dist/flowbite.js) }}"></script>
```

I copied one of the interactive elements I wanted to work with and voila, it worked perfectly fine.

PS: I skipped the below section and didn't include it in any file in my project:

```
import 'flowbite';
```

**This may not be the ideal solution, but it works.**

Answer (score 0):

Just only add this line of code to the `tailwind.config.js` file

```js
plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')
],
```